# Can't ping DC IP and connecting to domain results in an error (

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-server-2016, static-ip

I've set my Windows 10 DC to a static IP, and it is as follows:

- IP: 192.168.2.2
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Default Gateway: 192.168.2.1
- Preferred DNS Server: 192.168.2.2
- Alternate DNS Server: None

And with a Windows 7 unit attached to it via:

- IP: 192.168.2.11
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Default Gateway: 192.168.2.1
- Preferred DNS Server: 192.168.2.2
- Alternate DNS Server: 127.0.0.1

[IPconfig for my DC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTu1O.png)
[IPconfig for my Win7 unit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjZEj.png)

I can't seem to ping Client to my DC, nor can I connect it to the domain. On my DC it seems to detect my DC's name, which for privacy's sake will be named 'foo.net'. What did I do wrong? I'm really stumped at this point. This is running on Oracle VirtualBox 6.0.12.

**Edit:**
Both VMs are running on the same machine, as well as both running on the NAT connection type as opposed to Bridged.

Comment: Where is the DNS server that hosts DNS for your domain? There's not enough information in your question to explain why you can't ping.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator The DNS server is hosted by the DC server.

Comment: Probably a firewall issue then. If it's safe, turn them all off, see if it fixes the issue, then work from there.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Firewall is deactivated on both VMs. Still pinged and 'host destination unreachable'.

Comment: Also, setting the secondary DNS to the loopback address is non-standard and should be avoided, though that's not your problem.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Thanks. Still encountering the problem though. One thing I do note is that I can't access the internet as well, but I doubt that's the problem, considering I didn't intentionally set up this domain to be able to connect online. I'm completely stumped why this doesn't work...

Comment: That's related. It means your network configuration of the VMs is wrong. Unfortunately I don't know VirtualBox and can't offer any advice.